# Any other curves intersect it at at least 2 points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there an algebraic curve $C$, subset of an affine space, such that any curve that intersect it at all will intersect it at at least 2 points? 2 actual point, not "2" in the sense of intersection number. In other word, for any $D$ such that there is a rational point $P\in C\bigcap D$ there must be rational point $Q\not=P$, such that $Q\in C\bigcap D$.

The question seemed much harder without allowing to cheat by using intersection number. Any clues?

Comment: It seems already impossible that there is a curve that has nonempty intersection with every curve...

Comment: @Slade: sorry, I forgot a hypothesis.

Comment: One observation: this is certainly impossible in dimension greater than two: cut $C$ with a generic hyperplane $H$ to get a finite set of points, then choose a line in $H$ that passes through only one of them.